# Fetching sorted data from server in chunk?

Tags: java, oracle, algorithm, sorting, web-applications

I need to implement the feature where I need to display the customer names in ascending or descending fashion (along with other customer data) from oracle database.

1. Say I display first 100 names from DB in desc order.
2. There is button show more which will display next 100 names .
3. I am planning to fetch next records based on last index . So in step 2 I will fetch 101 to 200 names
4. But problem here is what if just before step 2, name was updated by some other user. 
   In that case name can be skipped(if name was updated to `X` to `A`) or duplicated((if name was updated to `A` to `Z`)) if I fetch records by index in step 2

Consider on first page displayed records names are from `Z` to `X`.

How can I handle this scenario where i can display the correct records without skip or duplicate ?

One way I Can think of is to fetch all records ID's in memory (either at webserver memory or cursor memory), store it as temporary result and then return the data from there instead of real data.But if i have million of records athen it will be load on memory either webserver or DB memory.

What is best approach and how do other sites handle this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want each user to view a fixed snapshot of the table data, then you will have to do some caching behind the scenes.  You have a valid concern of what would happen if, when requesting page 2, serveral new records landed on what would have been page 1, thus causing the same information to be viewed again on page 2.  Well, playing the devil's advocate, I could also argue that a user might also be viewing records which were deleted and are no longer there.  This could be equally bad in terms of user experience.

The way I have usually seen this problem handled is to just do a fresh query for each page.  Since you are using Oracle, you would likely be using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`.  It is possible that there could be a duplicated/missing record problem, but unless your data is very rapidly changing, it may be a minor one.

Comment: Yeah I am already doing fresh query with offset/rownum as you suggested. I am wondering how big sites like amazon etc handles this scenario. Are they also fine with duplicate/missing or they go for flawless approach with caching at back end

Comment: @emilly Based on what I have seen, they don't follow the pattern of taking an entire snapshot of the dataset.